# Stop watching folder changes in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i'm working on a  react project where user can uploads files,and the problem that i'am facing is when i upload a file to the server and save that file into folder called uploads which lives in the public folder,then when this process finished the page refreshed that's because the app watching for any changes and refresh the page
and i know that i can stop this by edit the webpackdevserver.config File but i don't know how to do that.
webpackdevserver.config:

```
// @remove-on-eject-begin
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
// @remove-on-eject-end
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const errorOverlayMiddleware = require('react-dev-utils/errorOverlayMiddleware');
const evalSourceMapMiddleware = require('react-dev-utils/evalSourceMapMiddleware');
const noopServiceWorkerMiddleware = require('react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware');
const ignoredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/ignoredFiles');
const redirectServedPath = require('react-dev-utils/redirectServedPathMiddleware');
const paths = require('./paths');
const getHttpsConfig = require('./getHttpsConfig');

const host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
const sockHost = process.env.WDS_SOCKET_HOST;
const sockPath = process.env.WDS_SOCKET_PATH; // default: '/sockjs-node'
const sockPort = process.env.WDS_SOCKET_PORT;

module.exports = function(proxy, allowedHost) {
  return {
    // WebpackDevServer 2.4.3 introduced a security fix that prevents remote
    // websites from potentially accessing local content through DNS rebinding:
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/887
    // https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a
    // However, it made several existing use cases such as development in cloud
    // environment or subdomains in development significantly more complicated:
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2271
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2233
    // While we're investigating better solutions, for now we will take a
    // compromise. Since our WDS configuration only serves files in the `public`
    // folder we won't consider accessing them a vulnerability. However, if you
    // use the `proxy` feature, it gets more dangerous because it can expose
    // remote code execution vulnerabilities in backends like Django and Rails.
    // So we will disable the host check normally, but enable it if you have
    // specified the `proxy` setting. Finally, we let you override it if you
    // really know what you're doing with a special environment variable.
    disableHostCheck:
      !proxy || process.env.DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK === 'true',
    // Enable gzip compression of generated files.
    compress: true,
    // Silence WebpackDevServer's own logs since they're generally not useful.
    // It will still show compile warnings and errors with this setting.
    clientLogLevel: 'none',
    // By default WebpackDevServer serves physical files from current directory
    // in addition to all the virtual build products that it serves from memory.
    // This is confusing because those files won’t automatically be available in
    // production build folder unless we copy them. However, copying the whole
    // project directory is dangerous because we may expose sensitive files.
    // Instead, we establish a convention that only files in `public` directory
    // get served. Our build script will copy `public` into the `build` folder.
    // In `index.html`, you can get URL of `public` folder with %PUBLIC_URL%:
    // <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In JavaScript code, you can access it with `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`.
    // Note that we only recommend to use `public` folder as an escape hatch
    // for files like `favicon.ico`, `manifest.json`, and libraries that are
    // for some reason broken when imported through webpack. If you just want to
    // use an image, put it in `src` and `import` it from JavaScript instead.
    contentBase: paths.appPublic,
    contentBasePublicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
    // By default files from `contentBase` will not trigger a page reload.
    watchContentBase: true,
    // Enable hot reloading server. It will provide WDS_SOCKET_PATH endpoint
    // for the WebpackDevServer client so it can learn when the files were
    // updated. The WebpackDevServer client is included as an entry point
    // in the webpack development configuration. Note that only changes
    // to CSS are currently hot reloaded. JS changes will refresh the browser.
    hot: true,
    // Use 'ws' instead of 'sockjs-node' on server since we're using native
    // websockets in `webpackHotDevClient`.
    transportMode: 'ws',
    // Prevent a WS client from getting injected as we're already including
    // `webpackHotDevClient`.
    injectClient: false,
    // Enable custom sockjs pathname for websocket connection to hot reloading server.
    // Enable custom sockjs hostname, pathname and port for websocket connection
    // to hot reloading server.
    sockHost,
    sockPath,
    sockPort,
    // It is important to tell WebpackDevServer to use the same "publicPath" path as
    // we specified in the webpack config. When homepage is '.', default to serving
    // from the root.
    // remove last slash so user can land on `/test` instead of `/test/`
    publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1),
    // WebpackDevServer is noisy by default so we emit custom message instead
    // by listening to the compiler events with `compiler.hooks[...].tap` calls above.
    quiet: true,
    // Reportedly, this avoids CPU overload on some systems.
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/293
    // src/node_modules is not ignored to support absolute imports
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1065
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: ignoredFiles(paths.appSrc),
    },
    https: getHttpsConfig(),
    host,
    overlay: false,
    historyApiFallback: {
      // Paths with dots should still use the history fallback.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/387.
      disableDotRule: true,
      index: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
    },
    public: allowedHost,
    // `proxy` is run between `before` and `after` `webpack-dev-server` hooks
    proxy,
    before(app, server) {
      // Keep `evalSourceMapMiddleware` and `errorOverlayMiddleware`
      // middlewares before `redirectServedPath` otherwise will not have any effect
      // This lets us fetch source contents from webpack for the error overlay
      app.use(evalSourceMapMiddleware(server));
      // This lets us open files from the runtime error overlay.
      app.use(errorOverlayMiddleware());

      if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
        // This registers user provided middleware for proxy reasons
        require(paths.proxySetup)(app);
      }
    },
    after(app) {
      // Redirect to `PUBLIC_URL` or `homepage` from `package.json` if url not match
      app.use(redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath));

      // This service worker file is effectively a 'no-op' that will reset any
      // previous service worker registered for the same host:port combination.
      // We do this in development to avoid hitting the production cache if
      // it used the same host and port.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2272#issuecomment-302832432
      app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrlOrPath));
    },
  };
};
```

and here where is store the files uploaded:
[structureAPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vrV4.png)

So my question is Like so:
How do i can edit webpackdevserver.config File to stop watching uploads File ?
i have been searching for this problem for two days and didn't fix it.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
 watchOptions: {
      ignored: ignoredFiles(paths.appSrc),
    },
```

This is indeed where ignored path are listed but `ignoredFiles(paths.appSrc)` is not the src folder. If you look higher you see `ignoredFiles.js` comes from the `react-dev-utils` module.

```
const ignoredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/ignoredFiles');
```

With react create app, the default `ignoredFiles.js` returns the `node_modules` folder which speeds up things by avoiding the watcher to go through all modules. Now it is possible to add more folders as `watchOptions.ignored` [accepts an array](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) So you can add your `uploads` path directly in the watchOptions.

```
 watchOptions: {
      ignored: [ignoredFiles(paths.appSrc), yourUploadPath],
    },
```

Comment: I'm also facing a same problem, Please can you explain clearly how to fix it?

Comment: Look at your `webpackDevServer.config.js`, and update the `watchOptions` with adding the path you want to exclude as writen abode with `yourUploadPath`. If you want it more relative, look how the function `ignoredFiles` is made in `node_modules/react-dev-utils/ignoredFiles.js`.

Comment: /**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const escape = require('escape-string-regexp');

module.exports = function ignoredFiles(appSrc) {
  return new RegExp(
    `^(?!${escape(
      path.normalize(appSrc + '/').replace(/[\\]+/g, '/')
    )}).+/node_modules/`,
    'g'
  );
};
I want to ignore the public folder.
Please can you fix it?