# How can I handle the multiple select box in react in a single state

Tags: html, reactjs, select

**My initial State**

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
country : "",
nationality : "",
})
```

**My first select tag :**

```
<select> //select for country
<option>Nepal<option/>
<option>USA<option/>
</select>
```

**My second select tag :**

```
<select> //select for nationality 
<option>Nepali<option/>
<option>Ameracain<option/>
</select>
```

**At the end , I need all the selected values of both select tag in the single state.**

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
    country : "Nepal",
    nationality : "Nepali",
    })
```

Comment: This might be helpful.
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61508732/11863236)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the name property and then use the multiple handle function in the React doc

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    country: "Nepal",
    nationality: "Nepali"
  });
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const {name,value}= e.target
 setState({...state,[name]:value})
    
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select name="country"  value={state.country} onChange={handleChange}>
        //select for country
        <option>Nepal</option>
        <option>USA</option>
      </select>
      My second select tag :
      <select name="nationality" value={state.nationality} onChange={handleChange}>
        //select for nationality
        <option>Nepali</option>
        <option>Americain</option>
      </select>
      {JSON.stringify(state)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[here is a sample based on your example](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-chaum-zm42r)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    country: "Nepal",
    nationality: "Nepali"
  });
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const copy = { ...state };
    switch (e.target.name) {
      case "country":
        copy.country = e.target.value;
        break;
      case "nationality":
        copy.nationality = e.target.value;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    setState(copy);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select name="country" onChange={handleChange}>
        //select for country
        <option>Nepal</option>
        <option>USA</option>
      </select>
      My second select tag :
      <select name="nationality" onChange={handleChange}>
        //select for nationality
        <option>Nepali</option>
        <option>Ameracain</option>
      </select>
      {JSON.stringify(state)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works but is is possible work with a single handle onchange??

Comment: I need your small help.. will you??

Comment: If I can, I will help.

Comment: Can we just get connected in the google meet ?? plz

Comment: Sorry I can't. You can send here.

Comment: Okay thank you, problem solved Thank u so much for responding me.. Plese would you mind to upvote my question :)

Comment: hello, mr @Almad.. i have some issue.. When i upload a file from react and express, the uploaded file is moved in public folder and when public folder changes my app reloads. is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the issue, would you please explain more.

Comment: yes, Firstly,, user pick up a file from input type file. The file  is sent to my express backend and it moves towards the public folder i.e public/Images. The problem is.. when  a new file is added in that Images folder my whole react app get reloads. I need to fix that problem. Is there any way to fix it out??

Comment: Yes the problem is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301585/stop-watching-folder-changes-in-reactjs